# How Can I make a search engine in unity3d??=

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I want to make an app with unity3d that user can search something in the game.
for Example there all 14 Items In my game if user click in item 5 it will describe about that item.
Now I want to make a search engine that user can search by the name or id or something else of the items.
Is it possible with Unity3D if Yes,So How???
Please Guide me.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far, and where exactly are you having trouble?

Comment: It is possible and usually not hard at all from a code POV. Where are you having problems exactly?

Comment: I havent start it yet I want to know is it possible and What should i know for making a search engine in unity?

Comment: StackOverflow does not write code for you. It is possible to do what you want in unity but I would not go as far to call it a search engine. What you want is to iterate over a List of items given a certain criteria. I suggest you read up on LinQ if you are using c# in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if you are still looking for an answer but if yes, then you can make it by providing the tag and let user search for the tag and it will come up with the particular reply.